# Access FAT32 partition from RHEL

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, fat32

AFIK, RHEL has built-in support for FAT32. So, I formatted additional partition on the disk with FAT32 and now I want to open it in RHEL 5.8. How can I do this? I don't see this partition in Computer or File Browser programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check with e.g. `cfdisk` from the command line on which device your partition resides. Then try to manually mount it to see if it works (e.g. using `mount /dev/sdXX /directory/to/mount/it` as root). If that works, you can add it to the `/etc/fstab` file to be found automatically next time. Place an additional line into that file which looks like

```
/dev/sdg1 /mnt/fatdisk     vfat    rw,user,iocharset=iso8859-1     0       0
```

where `/dev/sdg1` should be replaced by the device you figured out with cfdisk, `/mnt/fatdisk` by the directory to mount it to, and everything else should be OK.

**For reference:** I opened /dev directory, and found sda, sda1, sda2, sda3 files. Starting from sda, I executed:

```
[root@localhost alex]# mkdir /mnt/fat32
[root@localhost alex]# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/fat32
[root@localhost alex]# cd /mnt/fat32
[root@localhost fat32]# ls
... files I expect to see ...
```

Thanks to Izzy for the answer.

Comment: "cfdisk: command not found" What package should I install to execute this command?

Comment: BTW, some articles suffesr to use Hardware Browser for this. But I cannot find this program in the menu. Another suggestion, to install hwbrowser, doesn't work as well: No package hwbrowser available.

Comment: on Redhat, cfdisk should be in the package, hm, cfdisk ;)

Comment: yum output: "Unable to read consumer identity; Setting up Install Process; No package cfdisk available." I am using evaluation version, maybe this is the reason update doesn't work?

Comment: Don't know, I'm not running Redhat. I just checked with [RPMSeek](http://www.rpmseek.com/rpm-pl/cfdisk.html?hl=en&cx=0::) -- [RPMFind](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=cfdisk&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=) also reports this package. Maybe it is in some repository you have not enabled -- in that case, you can try one of the mentioned links to download the appropriate package and install it manually with `rpm -ivh cfdisk*.rpm`

Comment: Btw: Thanks for the edit -- makes it easier for others to see the solution straight away ;)